# Get euler rotation from two direction vectors

Tags: java, opengl, rotation, linear-algebra

I currently working on 3D gravity simulation. I have two vectors to represent normal vectors of up and front faces of a cube.

- up - `u`
- front - `v`

**How to get the euler rotation of that cube?**

I tried to project `u` and `v` onto those planes that use XYZ-axis as normal vector and get the angle between XYZ-axis and those projected vector to get rotation along with XYZ-axis.

```
rotation.x = Vector.projectOnPlane(
        new Vector3f(gravityVec).negate(), //pointing upward
        new Vector3f(1, 0, 0)).normalize() //project onto yz-plane
        .angle(new Vector3f(0, 1, 0)) //angle to y-axis

rotation.y = Vector.projectOnPlane(
        new Vector3f(zDir).negate(), //pointing forward
        new Vector3f(0, 1, 0)).normalize() //project onto xz-plane
        .angle(new Vector3f(1, 0, 0)) //angle to x-axis

rotation.z = Vector.projectOnPlane(
        new Vector3f(gravityVec).negate(), //pointing upward
        new Vector3f(0, 0, 1)).normalize() //project onto xy-plane
        .angle(new Vector3f(0, 1, 0)) //angle to y-axis
```

where function `projectOnPlane` is

```
public static Vector3f projectOnPlane(Vector3f vec, Vector3f planeNormal)
{//project vec on a plane that use planeNormal as normal vector
    return new Vector3f(vec).sub(new Vector3f(vec).mul(new Vector3f(planeNormal))
            .div(planeNormal.length() * planeNormal.length()).mul(planeNormal)).normalize();
}
```

But it didn't meets my expectation.

It works when x and z are both close to 0. But when I move to another place, it went wrong.

[My Expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGcig.png)

Comment: What does "it didn't works correctly" mean? Are you getting some error? What are the results vs expectations?

Comment: @Amongalen result isn't what i expected.

Comment: Then edit the question and add what the result was and what you expected.